# Mac Command line mkv audio only transcode

Tags: video, mkv, transcode, m4v

I have a mkv-file with h264 video and one 5.1 audio track.
I would like to have a m4v file with h264 video, down-mixed audio and 5.1 sound using the command line.

I could use sublerCLI to convert to m4v, but it does not transcode the audio.

I could use handbrakeCLI to convert to m4v, but handbrake always transcodes the video as well, which I rather don't want to do.

What tools could I use to do this in an one-stop solution? Or which tools would you use for the individual steps?

Daniel

Answer (score 0):

[FFmpeg](http://ffmpeg.org/) is definitely the go-to option for CLI video processing.

Have a look at [the docs](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html), but it sounds like you'll want `-codec:v copy` `-codec:a copy` and then some more advanced [audio manipulation](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Audio-Options) and stream addition using [`-map`](http://ffmpeg.org/ffmpeg.html#Advanced-options).  As FFmpeg has something of a steep learning curve, I'd recommend working out the audio down-mixing first, and then work on adding the extra audio stream.